# Add column to table form to show value from a query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have table `x`, where `x.b` is the primary key:

```
+-----+-----+
|  a  |  b  |
+-----+-----+
| xyz | 123 |
| abc | 456 |
| abc | 999 |
+-----+-----+
```

Table `y`, where `y.b` is the foreign key for `x.b`:

```
+----+-----+-------+
| ID |  b  |   c   |
+----+-----+-------+
|  1 | 123 | x105  |
|  2 | 123 | a309  |
|  3 | 456 | b123  |
|  4 | 999 | q234  |
|  5 | 999 | z525  |
+----+-----+-------+
```

A query `yQuery` based on `y` to find the value of `c` for the highest `ID` for each `b`, which results in:

```
+----+-----+-------+
| ID |  b  |   c   |
+----+-----+-------+
|  2 | 123 | a309  |
|  3 | 456 | b123  |
|  5 | 999 | z525  |
+----+-----+-------+
```

I have a form `xForm` that's currently displaying table `x`.  I want to add a column that shows the `c` result from `yQuery`, so that `xForm` would look like this:

```
+----+-----+-------+
| ID |  b  |   c   |
+----+-----+-------+
|  2 | 123 | a309  |
|  3 | 456 | b123  |
|  5 | 999 | z525  |
+----+-----+-------+
```

I tried adding a textbox to `xForm` where the control source of the textbox is:

```
=[yQuery]![c]
```

But that just gave me a column of **#Name?** errors.  I'm not sure how to set up the textbox so that its source is the `xForm!ID` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to have the form bound to a query that pulls the information from table [x] joined with query [yQuery] on [ID]. However, if [yQuery] has a `GROUP BY` clause then any query that incorporates [yQuery] might produce a recordset that is not updateable.

Another option would be to use a `DLookup()` as the Control Source for the textbox in question, something like

```
=DLookup("c","yQuery","ID=" & [ID])
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just use this dlookup instead:

=DLookup("[c]","yQuery","[b] = " & [Control Name for B in your form])

or maybe

=DLookup("[c]","yQuery","[b] = """ & [Control Name for B in your form] & """")

if b is not numeric

Comment: @Gord Thompson, you got in just before me!!